# Error pulling data into ComboBox2: According to the index selected in ComboBox1

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am trying to pull data from the database into ComboBox2 according to the index selected in ComboBox1, but I get an error, what is the reason?

Error CS1503 2 argument: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType'

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      
    string selectedValue = (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue;

    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(""))
    {

        connection.Open();

        var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE material_type = Value", connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", selectedValue , NpgsqlDbType.Char);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add(reader["brand_name"]);
        }
 
        connection.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget that `NpgsqlCommand` is disposable too.

Comment: I have used once.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You have to dispose every disposable. Using a `using` once doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the parameters of [AddWithValue()](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue_System_String_NpgsqlTypes_NpgsqlDbType_System_Object_) in the wrong order.

```
public NpgsqlParameter AddWithValue(
    string parameterName, 
    NpgsqlDbType parameterType, 
    object value)
```

Your call should look something like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", NpgsqlDbType.Char, selectedValue);
```

Comment: I  changed like this and it  gives this error " : 'Parameter Value must be set' "

Comment: I assume you need to fix your sql command. AFAIK named parameters start with `@` see [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#parameters) ->  `... WHERE material_type = @Value`

Comment: `connection.Open();
                    var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE material_type = @Value ", connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", NpgsqlDbType.Char, selectedValue);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox3.Items.Add(reader["brand_name"]);
                    }
                    connection.Close();`

I changed like this but still same error.

Comment: Try `AddWithValue("@Value", ...) `. I also think you should remove the line `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` since you want to query with reader

Comment: I did but same error idk whats the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I fix the error with this change.

```
        comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I forgot to add this code block to my form_load.

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: Idk. It fixed after that.

Comment: But it wasn't because of this.